# Typescript cast return type of subscription from {}[] to Array<Array<any>>

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do the following but I am getting a syntax error under monthData inside my 2nd for loop.

```
Observable.forkJoin(observableArray)
  .subscribe(monthArray => {

    console.log(monthArray)

    for (let monthData of monthArray) {
      for (let dataEntry of monthData) {
        // do somehting with dataEntry which is an object
      }
    }
  }
```

It is complaining that

> type {} is not an array type or string type

So when I hover over monthArray, the type of it is {}[].

However, I am 100% sure that the returned monthArray is array of type array as shown in the image

[image: screen shot]

Is there a way to cast monthArray from {}[] to

> `Array<Array<any>>>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the types are wrong here, RXJS5 is designed with TypeScript in mind and normally has very good typings. Nonetheless, you should be able to do something like this in your case:

```
 Observable.forkJoin(observableArray)
  .subscribe(arr => {
    const monthArray = arr as Array<Array<any>>;
    for (let monthData of monthArray) {
      for (let dataEntry of monthData) {
        // do somehting with dataEntry which is an object
      }
    }
  }
```

Check out [this nice writeup on type assertions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) if you're interested in learning more.